# meteor 1.0 - how to access packages content locally?

Tags: meteor, package

I'd like to understand: when I install a package, where is is stored locally?

I mean the directory structure that I can see on github. I've been looking in username/.meteor/packages.

I can indeed see a list of my packages in this directory but the package content doesn't seem to be there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run "meteor remove owner:packageName" to get rid of the external package.

Clone the package and copy or link it to /yourApp/packages/packageName

Run "meteor add owner:packageName" to add the local version.

That's all.

See: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=flGh4nHnETg